# WCF Activation exception - Base address for service not provided

Tags: .net, wcf, workflow-foundation, endpoint

ServiceActivationException: The service '//Service.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: Base addresses for the services are not provided. Provide at least one base address.

I have provided base address in the web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="WFService.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="WFService.Service1Behavior">
    <endpoint name="json" address="http://localhost:3003/WFServiceHost/Service.svc/json" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingConfig" contract="WFService.IService" behaviorConfiguration="WFServiceJsonEndpointBehavior"/>
    <host>
      **<baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:3003/WFServiceHost/Service.svc"/>
      </baseAddresses>**
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
```

In service.svc - I have Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WorkflowServiceHostFactory"

Any idea, what the resolution for it?

Answer (score 1):

baseAddress should not include Service.svc

```
    <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WFService.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="WFService.Service1Behavior">
        <endpoint name="json" address="json" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingConfig" contract="WFService.IService" behaviorConfiguration="WFServiceJsonEndpointBehavior"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:3003/WFServiceHost/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
```

Comment: Sure. I will try out. are you using .net 4.0? if so, can you post sample service.svc line?

Comment: its not working. even with service.svc it shouldn't say that base address is not provided. As there is still wrong address! Exception- 
[InvalidOperationException: Base addresses for the services are not provided. Provide at least one base address. ]
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.WorkflowServiceHostFactory.GetTypeFromString(String typeString, Uri[] baseAddresses) +255471
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.WorkflowServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses) +118
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.CreateService(String normalizedVirtualPath)